# Increment number inside a recurring event in Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar

Is there a way to automatically increment a number inside of a recurring event in Google Calendar?

Basically, what I'd like to do is add an event that tells me how old my daughter is, by week and by month, until she is two.

My memory is terrible and it sucks to stop and count the weeks every time I need to know this.

Comment: My friend, you'd seem a lot nerdier if you used a [counter](http://www.amazon.com/Robic-M-357-Tally-Counter/dp/B0007SXJTO/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1293842557&sr=8-1) for this purpose ;-).

Comment: This was my question but it appears to have been moved incorrectly from superuser.com (my login always carried over from stack to superuser but not superuser to web apps).

Anyway, I want to do this so it'll sync with my Android phone :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was looking to do something similar for a 90-day workout routine. I ended up writing a simple bash script, using GoogleCL, that added an event for each of the next 90 days with the week and day number of the course in the title of the event.

Something similar could easily be done to count the age of your daughter. A search for GoogleCL should bring up needed info.

I guess the drawback is that the events are not "linked" like a recurring event is if you want to make a change later.

@digitxp Maybe this is an even nerdier solution?

Comment: Not ideal but the best solution available. Thanks!

Comment: I believe "GoogleCL" in this answer refers to [googlecli](https://code.google.com/archive/p/googlecl/) which was a fantastic program, but unfortunately on 8-Jun-2015 it was permanently disabled due to upstream changes in authentication handling

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to do the same, and this [site](http://optics.eee.nottingham.ac.uk/matt/weeknumbers/weeknumbers_form.php) generates an arbitrary weekly event.

> Arbitrary week number generator for ical compatible calendars
>
> If you require week numbers for you calendar but your week one does
>   not on the first week of the year you have some problems. Google
>   Calendar and several other gizmos offer week numbers but they all
>   start on the first week in January. This php script can help.
>
> Instructions: enter a name for your calendar, choose the date to match
>   the first day of the first week for your week one and press the do it
>   button. The script will take you to a directory where your week number
>   calendar is stored. Save this to your computer and then import it into
>   your calendar. In google calendars I recommend creating a new calendar
>   called week numbers and then importing the events to this (it makes it
>   easier to delete the dates if you go wrong and makes it easy to change
>   colours etc etc). the import function is via the "gear" that appears
>   top right: calendar settings:calendars:import calendar. Remeber to
>   import to "week numbers" for ease of use.

Beware, create an extra calendar to import the ical to, because it might be difficult to clean it if you make some mistake.

Answer (score 1):

It will take a little bit of work, but you could create a CSV in Google Spreadsheets as outlined per "[Advanced: Create or edit CSV or iCal files before importing](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37118?hl=en)".

Google Spreadsheet would allow you to [AutoFill](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/75509?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) (and increment) the week numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This was my question but it appears to have been moved incorrectly from superuser.com (my login always carried over from stack to superuser but not superuser to web apps).

Anyway, I want to do this so it'll sync with my Android phone :)