# Iterative Calendar events in Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Increment number inside a recurring event in Google Calendar](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10850/increment-number-inside-a-recurring-event-in-google-calendar)

I want to be able to iteratively add events to a Google Calender like this:

> - Week one Day 1: Event #1
> - Week two Day 1: Event #2
> - Week three Day 1: Event #3

Each event is named the exact same except for the number after.  Any ways of accomplishing this without manually entering into the calendar?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10850